# Fire function to other

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to fire function in on.click event.

I have function:

```
    function updateTree(path){
    console.log("yes");
    }
updateTree("/");
```

lower:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fileManagerTree-li', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var actualPath = $(this).attr("data-path");
    updateTree(actualPath);
    console.log("yes2");
});
```

I've an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateTree is not defined

Why?

Comment: Error is quite clear, `updateTree` is not defined in same scope/global as your event handler

Comment: `updateTree is not defined`. This means it can't find updateTree(). Can it access that function on your page.

Comment: Okay, but how to run function from outside event?

Comment: Fix the scope problem. We can't tell you why you have a scope problem because you haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: If you have defined the function in window scope it should be available inside your on click event

Comment: I want to split my app to other functions, because the most part on instruction I am using more than one time. What is the best solution to make universal code working in onclick event?